# Android ICS Network Location not updating, real solution?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am seeing this on Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy S3

With just the network provider I'm not able to get GPS/positioning data in many occasions, until the phone is restarted. This is not a solution for my users.

It seems a lot of boilerplate GPS and positioning code , and tweaked code, simply requires different logic for Android 4.0+, and I would like to know how others have dealt with it.

Basically my app and other play store apps won't be able to get GPS/positioning data, but Google Maps app will still be able to.

Possible duplicate? Sure, but the accepted answers in related questions are all inadequate from what I've seen, and it needs to be determined if this is a known bug or if there are some new coding considerations that can be done that don't involve restarting the phone.

Comment: If you're saying that existing answers are inadequate, I suggest that you link to the corresponding questions and explain why the answers don't work for you.  Otherwise the question most definitely will be closed.

Comment: yes, network provider is not GPS, that makes sense that you are not able to get GPS if you demand network position

Comment: also, network position updates when you change position from the network point of view. usually when you change cell, which can be several hundred meters wide, or more. (I've seen 10km once)

Comment: @njzk2 semantics aside, network provider should give location information. Sometimes it doesn't give anything until the device is restarted

Comment: @AleksG the existing answers say restart the phone. Just take a cursory look through the "Related" questions on this page

Comment: I have been seeing this on multiple S3 devices too.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to listen for position callbacks. Have you added logging to be absolutely certain that `onLocationChanged()` is not being called?

Comment: @DavidWasser I should put logging in it that'll help since it doesn't happen all the time, tough to debug

Comment: If the user has no Internet, you will not get any reliable location updates using "network location". Are you perhaps seeing exactly this situation (no location updates) when you have no Internet connectivity?

Comment: @BenMaxRubinstein have you still been seeing this? I am getting more complaints coincidentally after google OTA updates rolled out last week. User restarts their phone and the problem is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to replace all my positioning code with Google Play Services.